# how to represent an integer array using java.util.BitSet ?

Tags: java, bitset

I need to represent an array of integers using BitSet. Can somebody explain
me the logic required to do this ?

Comment: I think the logic would be: 
Run through the integer array, test every bit and set this bit in the bitset like bitset.set(array_pos+bit_pos)

Answer (score 4):

You can represent a **set** of integers using `BitSet`, but not an arbitrary array. You will lose information about order and repetitions.

Basically, set the `n`th bit of the `BitSet` if and only if `n` appears in your set of integers.

```
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet();
int[] setOfInts = new int[] { /* Your array here */ };
for (int n : setOfInts) {
   bitSet.set(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first thought:
use BigInteger and create it like: new BigInteger(int value, int base). Then you can toString() it, and then create BitSet using that String(don't know how to do it without analyzing the string, however).
--
didn't read it right. That method only helps you to create an array of BitSet, not the whole BitSet that contains the whole array.
I don't know how to make array of integers to one bitSet. I guess you will need some kind of delimeters, but how to make good delimeter in binary - that's a good question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic would be: 
Run through the integer array, test every bit and set this bit in the bitset like bitset.set(array_pos+bit_pos)

Comment: int nums[] = {2, 1}.

When arrayPos is 0, you set 2 (0 + 2).

When arrayPos is 1, you set 2 again (1 + 1).